# Multiarch jpeglib for Cimg with android Ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, libjpeg, cimg

I have an android application that uses the Cimg library for image processing  using the ndk.

To work properly, cimg need the libpng library and the libjpeg library.

I don't have any problem with the png library but i need a multi arch version of libjpeg to make cimg work properly otherwise than with armeabi.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Are you building your applications for multiple architectures and just need help with the build setup?

Comment: I am, i know how to use the ndk to build native applicatiions, but not how to use the jpeglib for multiarch.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that libjpeg is *de facto* standard for all reasonable Android distributions and forks. You can extract it from a relevant system image of an AOSP emulator, if you want to satisfy the linker. You can even redistribute these libs with your app, but I am not a loyer, and am not responsible for any licensing or patent issues that may pop up.

On the other hand, the library you find in /system/lib may not have some latest features you might want, and be less optimized than, e.g. libjpeg-turbo.

You can build libjpeg or libjpeg-turbo yourself from sources, but this may require some advanced skills, especially if your build machine runs Windows.